# Javascript returning dataset from function to xmlhttprequest get parameters

Tags: javascript, php, dataset

I have a data attribute that is populated with a php variable. The php variable is a numeric value.

```
<?php $userId = 123; ?>
<div class="agent-detail-info" data-id="<?= $userId ?>"></div>
```

I am trying to grab the value from the dataset and pass it to a get url parameter. I've put this into its own function for window.onload as the php prints the html dynamically.

```
function userData() {
  let infoWrap = document.querySelector(".agent-detail-info").dataset.id;
  console.log(infoWrap);
  return infoWrap;
}
window.onload = userData;

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open(
  "GET",
  `url&usertolookup=${userData()}`
);
```

Console.log(infoWrap) returns the correct value in console, but console shows an error and does not populate the get parameters

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataset') at userData**

I'm thinking this is happening because the request is running before the userData function is called and the DOM is not yet populated?

This works:

```
function userData() {
  let infoWrap = 123;
  return infoWrap;
}
```

I tried wrapping the request into a function that runs after the DOM is loaded but this also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the code at the end from `window.onload`, so it runs after the `.agent-detail-info` element is added to the DOM. Running `userData()` itself doesn't do anything.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open(
    "GET",
    `url&usertolookup=${userData()}`
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you this definitely answered the question - now I have an issue of chaining functions within the window.onload - Elements are created on the page after the response with the response data and I have a few functions and a function that runs through an inline onclick that call on these elements. Since they are now generated after the dom is loaded these functions are broken.

Comment: I will add the code to the question - the question asked is answered though, thank you

Comment: Everything that depends on DOM elements should be run from the `onload` function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Thank you.. I am still struggling to get the 3 functions working with an onload.. would you mind taking a look at the code I've appended to the original post?

Comment: Of you have a new problem, post a new question. Don't add to a question that's already been answered.